# Increase instead of dip in voltage in a AC to DC Motor Circuit

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis

I have a very simple circuit. 120 AC into a rectifier output to a 120 DC motor. No caps or resisters. Literally a rectifier a DC motor with a thermal protected. No more no less.

When I power on the voltage at the outlet goes to 165 and stays there until power down.

Cannot figure out the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Three phase system with single phase load? Or split phase with load and measurement on oppisite phases?

Comment: 120 V AC is the RMS (root mean square) level of the voltage. The peak voltage is \$ \sqrt 2\$ times that so that may be what you are seeing. Edit your question to explain (1) if you have any capacitors in your circuit and (2) whether the motor was running when you measured 165 V DC.

Comment: Single phase. This is a small appliance. A small vacuum pump to be specific.

Comment: @Transistor adjusted question. And yes motor was under power.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage?

Comment: @circuitbird appliance plugged in outlet and multi meter off the outlet connection screws.

Comment: Single phase load and you measured the voltage on the input? Show with a schematic!

Comment: Before or after the rectifier? Was you multimeter in DC or AC mode?

Comment: Motors are inductive which will skew the power factor which may confuse your meter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motor will produce back-EMF, depending on the RPM, which effectively acts as a generator. If the motor is not under load, the voltage at the bridge output approaches the *peak* voltage of the AC waveform, because at the peak voltage of 120VAC RMS no power will be transferred to the motor (just enough to replace that lost by bearing friction and windage). The diodes only allow power to be transferred *to* the motor.

That peak voltage is \$\sqrt{2}\cdot 120\$ = 170V approximately.

As the motor is more heavily loaded, you would expect the voltage you read at the bridge output to drop.

Comment: That makes very good sense to me. Do you think I should add a ferrite core to help with the emf?  Also do you think the emf could be detrimental to the gfci outlet?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything. The GFCI (if properly wired) only sees the AC input to the bridge  so it sees 120VAC as usually.  Do **not** run the 120VDC to a regular 120VAC outlet/receptacle/connector of any kind- use direct wiring or a specialized connector. There are way too many ways for that to go badly.